# How I can Process Big number of records with Laravel eloquent and MySql without server fails?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

The problem is that I have a huge list of emails (750,000 verified Emails ) and I want to loop on it against a users table that also has a huge number of records (800,000 users) and delete users that their
emails is not exists in the verified email list I tried to to use chunks , but I think I use it in wrong way, For example :

```
$users = User::query()->wherehas('emails_email')->chunk(10, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
          
        echo $user->name ;
     }
});
return response()->json($users)
```

Comment: I would not use laravel for this as a raw, multi table sql delete would be a lot more efficient from a performance point of view.

Comment: can you just mention a sample of code that implement your way to do that

Comment: See the answers to the duplicate question.

Comment: I'm not sure that numbers below 1m qualify as 'big'

Comment: so what you suggest to deals with this small numbers ?